# External stylesheet in Polymer custom element

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm wrapping a third-party control in a polymer 1.1 custom element. The control comes with a CSS file that I want to scope to my custom element. What is the recommended approach for doing this? Some possible options that come to mind are:

1. Include a plain old link tag that points to my css file in my custom element
2. Use an HTML import.
3. In Polymer 1.1 there's a new concept referred to as style modules which is supposed to supersede external sylesheets according to the polymer documentation: 
   https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html
   Is another approach to specify an external stylesheet within the style module?

I don't know whether any of the above approaches are feasible for my scenario.

**Update**

I tried using a style module as suggested in one of the answers below but for some reason the third-party css file specified in the style module was not loading. Any idea why?

my-style-module.html:

```
<dom-module id="my-style-module">
    <template>
        <link rel="import" href="http://url_of_third_party_css_file">
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

my-custom-element.html (sample):

```
<!-- import the module  -->
<link rel="import" href="my-style-module.html">

<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
  <template>
    <!-- include the style module by name -->
    <style include="my-style-module"></style>
    <style>:host { display: block; }</style>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </template>      
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0 deprecated way is here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets and I made a brief example here: http://polymerjs.newfivefour.com/post/126638694607/sharing-css-styles-across-elements Basically, you use the external CSS file you mentioned and use the custom import.

But now, as of 1.1, there's a new way, where you put your CSS into a component and include that via a HTML import and then a style include tag in the component: https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2015/08/13/1.1-release/ It seems like you should use this approach, although the deprecated will still work according to their blog post.

Comment: Just yesterday i was fiddling around with this issue. Since for this release Polymer is using the shady dom, global stylesheets (link tag the old fashioned way) seem to work normally. If you go the new Polymer way you probably end up with a not working stylesheet because all selectors are automatically namespaced to prevent bleeding into other dom-modules. In the dom-inspector scroll to the top and have a look at the style elements. There u see how polymer rewrites all stylesheet definitions...

Comment: The second and third links are broken. Can you please add the relevant parts of what was true at that time. Consider linking to the archive.org versions of these URLs anyway.